# Wing ide "run" button is greyed out unless I save the file

Tags: python, python-3.6, wing-ide

Whenever I create a new wing file in the wing IDE interface, I find the "run code" (play symbol) button is greyed out and I can't click it unless I save the file somewhere on my computer. It didn't used to to this.

This is annoying because it forces you to save every single code you write even if it's just 5 lines you've written to test something out.

I can't recall exactly when the button changed, I didn't notice it immediately. But I've updated both my wing IDE and python to the latest version. I've also shifted the directory that I keep all my python saves in, but I can't see why that would matter.

I've taken a look through settings, but I couldn't make much sense of it. I'm new to programming.

Comment: Since Wing IDE is closed source, someone can't look at the source history and determine where this change was introduced (and then look up a ticket tied to that changeset to determine why). You're probably best off asking through its commercial support mechanism.

Comment: That said, if I were writing a development tool myself, there's a good chance it would have the same limitation. Filenames impact how those files are executed -- a `.pyw` file runs without a console; a filename can be retrieved and inspected from the source itself; etc. If they previously defaulted to saving with a random temporary name and had someone file bugs because of that, or feeding the script on the interpreter's stdin and had bugs on account of *that*, I could certainly see the decision be to just drop the feature instead of working around those bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wing has never been able to debug an unsaved file.  I suspect you used Wing 101 previously and now use Wing Personal or Wing Pro where the toolbar buttons are a bit different and run things in the debugger instead of evaluating in the Python Shell.

You can still evaluate the file or a selection in the file in the Python Shell using the items in the Source menu.  As of Wing 6 you can also debug things you execute in this way by enabling debug in the Python Shell's Options menu.

You can also select a range in the file, click on the active range icon in top right of the Python Shell to make it the active range and then use the cog icon that appears in top right of the Python Shell whenever you want to reevaluate the range as you edit it in the editor.

Comment: Yeah the name wing 101 does ring a bell. I think that's the original one I downloaded a while ago. 
Perhaps I should revert to 101.